# Python virtualenv --system-site-packages iPython

Tags: python, virtualenv, ipython

I am using EPD on OS X and have ipython installed.  In my 'general' environment everything is functioning as expected.  I installed virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper to generate a dev environment.  I only want to install a small subset of 'new' modules (different versions), so I used:

`mkvirtualenv development --python=epd --system-site-packages`

Now what I would like to do is install ipython local to the virtual env.  I believe that this is the preferred installation method as other techniques include adding code to ipython startup.

which pip & which python report that the virtual env files are being called.  I can not install ipyhton though, because it already exists in my epd install.

Is it possible to create a virtualenv that uses the 'general' site-packages and then locally install ipython?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure, just tell pip to ignore the installed IPython:

```
pip install --ignore-installed ipython
```